Flatlist is not updating the state
FlatList is not showing the results of useInfiniteQuery.
const MemoizedCommunityPost = React.memo(CommunityPost);

const CommunityPostList: React.FC<PostListProps> = ({ communityId }) => {
  const { layout, fonts, gutters, borders } = useTheme();
  const [sortOption, setSortOption] = useState("new");
  const { data, isLoading, error, isFetching, refetch, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage } = useFetchCommunityPosts({
    communityId,
    orderBy: "createdAt",
    orderDirection: "DESC",
    limit: 25,
  });

  console.log("Render - Data:", data?.pages[0]?.posts.length, "Loading:", isLoading, "Fetching:", isFetching);

  const posts = useMemo(() => data?.pages.flatMap((page) => page.posts) || [], [data]);

  const renderPost = useCallback(
    ({ item }: { item: ExtendedPost }) => (
      <MemoizedCommunityPost post={item} style={[borders.border, borders.bottom_thin]} />
    ),
    [borders]
  );

  const ListHeaderComponent = useCallback(
    () => (
      <>
        <CommunityMetaHeader communityId={communityId} />
        <PostSorting currentSort={sortOption} onSortChange={setSortOption} />
      </>
    ),
    [communityId, sortOption]
  );

  const keyExtractor = useCallback((item: ExtendedPost) => item.id, []);

  const handleLoadMore = useCallback(() => {
    if (hasNextPage && !isFetching) {
      fetchNextPage();
    }
  }, [hasNextPage, isFetching, fetchNextPage]);

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={[layout.flex_1, layout.justifyCenter, layout.itemsCenter]}>
        <Text>Error: {error.message}</Text>
        <Text onPress={() => refetch()}>Tap to retry</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  // Show loading indicator only for initial load
  if (isLoading && !data) {
    return (
      <View style={[layout.flex_1, layout.justifyCenter, layout.itemsCenter]}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      key={`postlist-${posts.length}`}
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
      data={posts}
      renderItem={renderPost}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      contentContainerStyle={[layout.flex_1, gutters.paddingHorizontal_small]}
      onRefresh={refetch}
      refreshing={isFetching}
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      ListFooterComponent={isFetching ? <ActivityIndicator /> : null}
      ListEmptyComponent={
        !isLoading && !isFetching ? (
          <View style={[layout.flex_1, layout.justifyCenter, layout.itemsCenter]}>
            <Text>No posts found</Text>
          </View>
        ) : null
      }
      extraData={data}
    />
  );
};

Here, FlatList shows an infinite loading indicator until the app closes. I have tried to give different objects to extraData but I could not make it work.
Did I miss something?

First of all, I should say BRAVO. When it's your first experience with React Native. That's an awesome code. I think you should use isPending instead of isLoading. Whole the code is utterly correct. Also please add your console.log results.
